# ISO8601 dates parsed from XML have different Timezones

Tags: xml, date, datetime, iso8601

I have an XML segment that contains two dates in format e.g. 2016-03-22 and 2016-03-29. They are parsed from XML to String objects and then converted to ISO8601 compliant date objects. During this process, the 2016-03-22 is interpreted as Tue Mar 22 00:00:00 GMT 2016 while the second date gets interpreted as Tue Mar 29 00:00:00 BST 2016. You will see that one is in GMT TZ and the other in BST timezone. This means that calculating days between those dates results in a day less than I'd expect. The clocks go forward this year on 30th March and I am not sure if there is a correlation since this is happening for ranges of dates close to but no including March 30th. This year is also a leap year, cannot be sure if that also has a bearing on the dates involved.

Have you any thoughts on why this might happen?

Thanks,
Ger.

Comment: What is your locale?

Comment: Were the dates captured from a computer in BST timezone?  When parsing a string date to a DateTime object you must specify the timezone where the dates were captured.  The PC stores DateTimes using GMT.  A conversion is performed using computer TimeZone settings whenever a DateTime object is is converted from/to strings.  If data is captured in a different Time Zone than the PC setting the parser must be told which time zone setting data was collected.

Comment: The dates were submitted from a computer in GMT timezone. The dates are parsed from XML into string objects and then into date time objects. Since they are passed in from XML as YYYY-MM-DD format with no TZ info I consider the problem arises in the ISO8601 date parsing methods and that something in its implementation is at fault. But would like to understand why this might happen first.

Comment: What language/libarary is used for parsing the dates?

Comment: We have no idea what technology you are using. You say "then converted to ISO8601 compliant date objects" but you don't way what software was used for this conversion.

Comment: According to ISO 8601, a date like "2016-03-22" should be parsed as local (i.e. using the host system's time zone offset for that date). You don't mention the technology used for conversion, some have known issues. For example, Javascript (ECMAScript) parsers should treat the dates as UTC, but some will treat them as local and some as invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, most (if not all) European countries change to Daylight Savings Time on Sunday March 27. This also explains the BST (British Summer Time) time zone that you get when parsing "2016-03-29".

However, if you perform period or duration calculations based on input data that originally does not include time zone information, you should expect results like this.

If you are using Java, I suggest using the excellent java.time API, introduced in Java 8. If Java 8 is not an option, look for Joda Time or its C# (.NET) counterpart, Noda Time.